# How to replace custom HTML with actual HTML tags using JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Am using the following version of JSoup (along with Java 1.7):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My code:

```
public class HtmlTagUtils {

    private static String mockHtml = "<asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"1236ad76-7433-fs34-50d1-b12bdbc308899af\">"
+ "</asset-entity>\r\nAngelie Jolie was seen at Wholefoods with ex-beau Brad Pitt.\r\n <asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"2346fe7d-c175-c380-4ab2-dda068b42b033dvf\">"
+ "</asset-entity>\r\n- The majority of their kids were with them.\r\n<asset-entity type=\"video\" id=\"45064086-5d85-1866-4afc-a523c04c2b3e43b6\"> </asset-entity>\r\n";

    public static List<String> extractIdsForPhotos(String html) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = doc.select("asset-entity[type=photo]");
        List<String> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element element : elements) {
            String type = element.attributes().get("type");
            String id = element.attributes().get("id");
            photos.add(id);
        }
        return photos;
    } 

    public static List<String> extractIdsForVideos(String html) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = doc.select("asset-entity[type=video]");
        List<String> videos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element element : elements) {
            String type = element.attributes().get("type");
            String id = element.attributes().get("id");
            videos.add(id);
        }
        return videos;
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
        List<String> photoIds = extractIdsForPhotos(mockHtml);
        for (String photoId : photoIds) {
            System.out.println("\n\tphotoId: " + photoId);
        }

        List<String> videoIds = extractIdsForVideos(mockHtml);
        for (String videoId : videoIds) {
            System.out.println("\n\tvideoId: " + videoId);
        }
    }       
}
```

Receive the following output to stdout:

```
photoId: 1236ad76-7433-fs34-50d1-b12bdbc308899af
photoId: 2346fe7d-c175-c380-4ab2-dda068b42b033dvf
videoId: 45064086-5d85-1866-4afc-a523c04c2b3e43b6
```

Am able to find the necessary assets based on these ids but my question is how to replace the entire tag (along with its contents, inline) using JSoup (e.g. for photos):

```
<asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"4806ad76-7433-fs34-50d1-b12bdbc308899ad\">" + "</asset-entity>
```

with:

```
<img src="AngelinaJolie.jpg">
```

So the converted HTML would look like this:

```
"<img src="AngelinaJolie.jpg">\r\nAngelie Jolie was seen at Wholefoods with ex-beau Brad Pitt.\r\n <img src="BradPitt.jpg">
\r\n- The majority of their kids were with them.\r\n<video><source src="Brangelina.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>\r\n";
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent template engines. Unless there's an existing system that you're needing to replace exactly, use something like Thymeleaf.

Comment: @Chrylis I am not trying to reinvent template engines. Maybe my post was too detailed. I just want to know how to replace a custom HTML tag with content that I already have.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually change the tagName of the element and try replacing its attributes with your attributes.

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
        Elements elements = doc.select("asset-entity[type=photo]");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            element.tagName("img");
            element.removeAttr("type");
            element.removeAttr("id");
            element.attr("src","AngelinaJolie.jpg");
        }
        String formattedHtml = doc.html();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding... This is only for one tag, like I said, I have different tags (with different content - e.g.  photo and video). How can I do it if I had a list of different <img src> based on the list of ids?

Comment: If you have the src for the ids of the elements, for example, say hashmap containing id and its corresponding src then we can query the hashmap based on id and set the elements src.